# What is the right way to document usage of models?

Tags: php, phpdoc

What is the right way to document the usage of a `Model A` accessed in `Model B`? In this case i want to document the usage of `Excel`.

```
class Preview extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * Push file Data to Session
     *
     * @ ...
     */
    public static function push() {
        Session::put('data', Excel::get(self::file));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: The original title had the words "document model usage" which could be confused with the "document model" (i.e. mixing up 'document' the noun with 'document' the verb). I have edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I'm not a native english speaker...

Comment: It's fine. It is a fault with the English language not with you. But it was confusing first time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [@see annotation](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/see.html) to point to another class:

```
class Preview extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * Push file Data to Session
     *
     * @see Excel::get()
     * @see Session
     * @see http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php
     */
    public static function push() {
        Session::put('data', Excel::get(self::file));
    }
}
```

When generating the html documentation it should create an anchor tag that links to the documentation of the Excel class's get method, the Session class. and the php.net manual

Comment: How obvious... This is exactly what i'm look for. Thank you!